# How do we count subversion commits per user

Tags: svn

How do we count subversion commits per user

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This gives a quick histogram by counting  entries from the log in xml:

```
svn log -v --xml | grep '<author.*/author>' | sort $* | uniq -c | sort -rn

   1841 <author>joe</author><br>
    735 <author>jimbob</author><br>
    129 <author>sally</author><br>
     32 <author>mike</author>
```

Could tack on a sed command to clean things up more, but thats answers the posted question..

Comment: I know this is really old but I had problems running this command in **Windows** using **CYGWIN**: the fix is making sure your cygwin/bin path appears in front of the system32 path in **PATH** variable. As MSDOS has it's own **SORT** command.

Comment: 2. changing the **'** to **"** in grep '<author.*/author>'

3. changing sort $* to just sort

Comment: So it would look like this: **svn log -v --xml | grep "<author.*/author>" | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn**

Comment: Windows powershell version: svn log --xml | select-string -pattern '<author>[\s\S]*?<\/author>' | Group-Object

Answer (score 16):

Use the SVN dumps:

```
svn log -v --xml > logfile.log
```

Then you can either do the data mining by yourself, or use [**StatSVN**](http://www.statsvn.org/).

Another option, which uses shell commands only (and is actually kinda nice), is detailed [in this blog post](http://blogs.oracle.com/mikey/entry/count_svn_commits_for_each).

Comment: If all you are interested in is the username, you can omit -v, and even use -q. V is verbose, which will include the paths. -q will ommit even the commit message, making the log much smaller and easier to search through.If you know the username you can append '--search username'

Answer (score 5):

You could use StatSVN. But what do you want to achieve? commit count does not need to say *anything*!

Keep it in mind.

Comment: Not in a single day or week, but huge differences in the number of commits between developers working on more or less similar projects over time (lets say dayly average over a year) might tell us something.

Comment: I disagree and I think this is akin to counting the lines that someone edited which is also not accurate. For example, I can make a 1 line edit with 1 commit that took hours to find and which has greater impact than the hundreds of lines with dozens of commits that someone else made one day. 

If these 2 people are better at both types of work respectively and do them both often, just judging on commit count would not be an accurate representation of "who works more".

Answer (score 2):

[PanBI](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/panbi/index.php?title=Main_Page) also supports [Subversion analysis](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/panbi/index.php?title=Subversion), one of which is the number of commits per developer over a time period. You can see what it does in a few minutes in the [screencast](http://panbi.sourceforge.net/systems/subversion/olap.html).

There are 3 steps:

1. unpack the PanBI distributable
2. set the subversion URL in panbi.conf.xml
3. run the "run-all-no-worries" .bat or .sh script

Disclaimer: it's my own project.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a post-commit hook(trigger) on the server. Inside the trigger you can write info in a database or in a CSV file that can be processed later.

Answer (score 1):

Use SVN log

```
svn log -v --xml url > logfile.xml
```

For date range

```
svn log -v --xml <url> -r {2016-01-30}:{2016-05-30} > logfile.xml
```

eg: `svn log -v --xml http://repo.abc/xyz -r {2016-01-30}:{2016-05-30} > logfile.xml`

and then open the file in `notepad++.` The Find tool has a **count** button. Find by authorname or authorid, and use count button to find the number of commits by the person.

This can be executed from windows command prompt , but you need to add `'\'` before `'{'`. ie: `svn log -v --xml http://repo.abc/xyz -r \{2016-01-30}:\{2016-05-30} > logfile.xml`

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice stat option in Tortoise SVN client for Windows.
You access it from Repo-Browser "Statistics" Button.
You can specify the date range.
Filter on User, Paths, Comments content...